# Dynamically load new version of assembly (DLL)

Tags: c#, dll, windows-services

I created a Windows service.
My problem:
I have a constant reference to Library.dll (old version) and call one method in this assembly.
Once a day I download a new version of Library.dll to a specific folder.
Is it possible to load a new DLL at runtime and always call the new version of the method without reflection?

Comment: Do you need to be able to do this without your program stopping, or would your service restarting itself once a day be acceptable. (Restarting itself is actually the easier option, because then you don't need to deal with AppDomain's)

Comment: Assuming you are interested in loading new version at run-time (vs. restarting service) than linked duplicate covers most steps you need to follow.