# How to get DLL file auto updated in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, dll, service

I have already made Windows Service application which uses my DLL library (all in C#). It uses timer just to call a simple method from the DLL. I need to add a feature which will enable to auto update this library. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Are you the same person as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31641773/dynamically-load-new-version-of-assembly-dll#comment51233178_31641773) from a few days ago?

Comment: If you need to constantly update your dll, you might be doing something wrong. Could you note use an external datasource ? (file or database)